# How far from a matrix the rank does not decrease?

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, svd, semicontinuous-functions

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix, and suppose that $\text{rank}(A)=k$. Consider
$$ r_0=\sup \{r>0 \,\, | \,\, |B-A| \le r \Rightarrow \text{rank}(B) \ge k \}.$$

> Does $r_0$ depend only on the **smallest non-zero** singular value $\sigma_{\min}$ of $A$?

Clearly, $r_0 \le \sigma_{\min}$, since if we allow $|B-A| >\sigma_{\min}$, we can replace $\sigma_{\min}$ by zero. (keeping all the other components of the SVD the same).

Is it true that $r_0= \sigma_{\min}$? Even if this is false, I would still like to know whether $r_0$ depends only on  $\sigma_{\min}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose the $||.||_2$, then your conjecture is true, that is,

If $||B-A||_2<\sigma_k$, then $rank(B)\geq k$. Moreover, there is a matrix $B$ s.t. $rank(B)=k-1$ and $||B-A||_2=\sigma_k$.

cf. Eckart-Young-Mirsky Theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_spectral_norm)